# R - Purrr - Slicing using map(), or: How to slice list of tibbles of varying lengths based on NAs?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm trying to figure out how to slice or subset a list of tibbles of varying lengths based upon first appearance of a non-NA. All my tibbles are of varying dimensions with numerous NAs, but common for all is that they have some number of NAs in the first rows that I need to remove.

I am only interested in getting rid of the first number of rows while keeping all the following rows.

I've created a reprex that sort of illustrates my data:

```
tbl <- tibble(
  first = c(NA, 1, 2, 3, NA),
  second = c(NA, 1, NA, 3, NA),
  third = c(NA, 1, 2, NA, NA)
)

lst <- list(
  list1 = tbl,
  list2 = tbl,
  list3 = tbl
)

lst
$list1
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  first second third
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1    NA     NA    NA
2     1      1     1
3     2     NA     2
4     3      3    NA
5    NA     NA    NA

$list2
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  first second third
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1    NA     NA    NA
2     1      1     1
3     2     NA     2
4     3      3    NA
5    NA     NA    NA

$list3
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  first second third
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1    NA     NA    NA
2     1      1     1
3     2     NA     2
4     3      3    NA
5    NA     NA    NA
```

I've tried using `map()` in combination with `which.min()` and `is.na()` to try and slice based upon the first instance of non-NA, but cannot make it work.

```
sliced <- map(lst, slice, which.min(is.na):nrow())
```

All i get is the following error:

```
Error in which.min(is.na) : 
  cannot coerce type 'builtin' to vector of type 'double'
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can a first row be `NA, 2, 3` ? What would be the output in that case?

Comment: Yes, sorry. The subsetting/slicing will be dictated by first column of each tibble only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is.na` needs a vector. You may need to pass a particular column to it.

For example, using the first column you can do -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map(lst, ~.x %>% slice(which.max(!is.na(.[[1]])) : n()))


#$list1
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  first second third
#  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1      1     1
#2     2     NA     2
#3     3      3    NA
#4    NA     NA    NA

#$list2
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  first second third
#  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1      1     1
#2     2     NA     2
#3     3      3    NA
#4    NA     NA    NA

#$list3
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  first second third
#  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1      1     1
#2     2     NA     2
#3     3      3    NA
#4    NA     NA    NA
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use this method if the first column is also not named the same across all tibbles? ie. basically just always using the first column, no matter what name?

Comment: Yes, you can use `.[[1]]` instead of the column name. See the updated answer.

Comment: Works exactly as expected. Thanks